# How to run vstest.console.exe for Unit Test 64-bit platform

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, vstest

How to run vstest.console.exe targeting the 64-bit platform?

Unit Tests set to target platform x64 were failing to run on DevOps tools (VSTS/TeamCity/Octopus).

> ### [error]Error: None of the provided test containers match the Platform Architecture and .Net Framework settings for the test run.
>
> Platform: X86  .Net Framework: Framework45. Go to
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=330428 for more details on
> managing these settings.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Locally it is achieved by setting the tests on Visual Studio to run on x64 as default process.

> **Test** tab on VS > *Test Settings* > *Default Process Architecture* > **x64**

When using some DevOps tool, the platform can be specified in the script which runs the **vstest.console.exe**

> In my case, I'm using *Azure DevOps* Build Definitions, so I set my VS Test task to `/platform:x64` through a parameter when running **vstest.console.exe**.

```
vstest.console.exe "C:\Project\bin\x64\Release\Project.UnitTests.dll" "C:\Project\bin\x64\Release\Project.UnitTests.dll" /platform:x64 /logger:trx
```

Once it is set, all x64 targeting Unit Tests dlls will execute successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have vstest.console.exe under C:\
Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Mi
crosoft\TestWindow\

- from cmd go to the path where your projects dll are kept. 
  i.e. cd C:\Users\krakhil\Desktop\Notes\Practice Codes\VerifyExe\VerifyExe\bin\Debug

Press Enter

Then write -> "C:\
Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Mi
crosoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" VerifyExe.dll

Where VerifyExe.dll is the project dll i want to execute.